# write/read contents from a file in Linux FS using java script

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I have installed node.js and running a project(with all js files) on Apache Knox. I need to save some data to a file(HOME/Job_State.txt) in Linux FS and read its contents when needed to do some checksums. Iam new to js and looking for example code that does this. Kindly help me by providing some suggestions/pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `fs` (File System) module of node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');  
});

fs.readFile('message.txt', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback

There are synchronous versions too: `fs.writeFileSync()` and `fs.readFileSync()`

Comment: I assume console.log would print the data into logs. Is there a way to get the data into a variable so that I can use regex expressions to separate and validate contents of the file. Please correct me if Iam wrong.

Comment: `console.log` prints with newline to `stdout`. `data` is already a variable that you can use with regex!